# setPropertyActionListener is not passing the right value

Tags: jsf

i have an editor component  that displays the selected family (from a tree ) description

so after editing it the user click on save button in there i want to use this

```
 <f:setPropertyActionListener  target="#
            {projectTestManagementMB.selectedNodeDescription}" 
             value="projectTestManagementMB.selectedFamily.description" />
```

to pass the new value of the description to this variable selectedNodeDescription . but when i check it i found it containing the old value of `projectTestManagementMB.selectedFamily.description` and not the new one .

Here's the code :

```
<p:editor id="familyDescriptionEditor" value="#
     {projectTestManagementMB.selectedFamily.description}" width="600"/>  

      <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Save"   icon="ui-icon-disk"  
       actionListener="#{projectTestManagementMB.saveDescription}">
          <f:setPropertyActionListener  target="#
            {projectTestManagementMB.selectedNodeDescription}" 
             value="projectTestManagementMB.selectedFamily.description" />

      </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Why dont u use a void action and pass it as an argument?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ActionListener instance created and installed by this tag has the following behavior and contract.
>     Only create and register the ActionListener instance the first time the component for this tag is created.

So Try using the action attribute instead of actionListener :

```
   <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Save"   icon="ui-icon-disk"  action="#   
        {projectTestManagementMB.saveDescription}" >
          <f:setPropertyActionListener  target="#
         {projectTestManagementMB.selectedNodeDescription}" value="#
          {projectTestManagementMB.selectedFamily.description}" />
    </p:commandButton>
```